# How can I update the database table from a datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, datalist

I'm building an e-commerce website and I used a datalist to display my products and when I press the "Add to cart" button, they are supposed to be added to a database table but for some reason, the products are not being updated in the database table. Also, clicking on the 1st product gives an error saying "there is already an open reader" and the line showing the error is "int result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MWM1812
{
    public partial class productCatalog : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public enum MessageType { Success, Error, Info, Warning };
        protected void ShowMessage(string Message, MessageType type)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "ShowMessage('" + Message + "','" + type + "');", true);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }




        protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
            {
                Session["uid"] = 1;
                Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("PIDLabel");
                lblAtC.Text = lbl.Text;
                ShowMessage("Product successfully added to Cart", MessageType.Success);

                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MWM1812ConnString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

                conn.Open();

                string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblShoppingCart WHERE uid=@uid AND pid=@pid";
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["uid"]);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lblAtC.Text.Trim());
                using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        string sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE tblShoppingCart SET qty=qty+1 WHERE uid=@uid AND pid=@pid";
                        SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, conn);
                        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", 1);
                        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        //// Add code for adding parameters and executing sqlQuery2 
                        int result = comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {



                        string sqlQuery1 = "INSERT INTO tblShoppingCart (uid, pid, qty, dtShopped) VALUES (@uid, @pid, @qty, @dtShopped)";
                        SqlCommand comma = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery1, conn);
                        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["uid"]);
                        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lblAtC.Text);
                        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", 1);
                        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        int result = comma.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the code like this:

```
if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart") {
     bool productExists = false;

     Session["uid"] = 1;
     Label lbl = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("PIDLabel");
     lblAtC.Text = lbl.Text;
     ShowMessage("Product successfully added to Cart", MessageType.Success);

     string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MWM1812ConnString"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

     conn.Open();

     string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblShoppingCart WHERE uid=@uid AND pid=@pid";
     SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["uid"]);
     comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lblAtC.Text.Trim());

     using(SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader()) {    
        productExists = reader.HasRows;
     }

      if (productExists) {
       string sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE tblShoppingCart SET qty=qty+1 WHERE uid=@uid AND pid=@pid";

       // Add code for adding parameters and executing sqlQuery2 
      } else {



        string sqlQuery1 = "INSERT INTO tblShoppingCart (uid, pid, qty, dtShopped) VALUES (@uid, @pid, @qty, @dtShopped)";
        SqlCommand comma = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["uid"]);
        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lblAtC.Text);
        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", 1);
        //comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        int result = comma.ExecuteNonQuery();


      }     
    }
```

Notice the use of reader.HasRows property to determine if product already exists. Also, SqlDataReader is wrapped inside `using` block for disposing it off.

Comment: I tried it but it gives the same "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." error

Comment: Have you posted your complete code as part of the question? Also, at which line of code you are getting this exception?

Comment: Yes, this was the whole page's code. the issue is with int result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: I think your insert command name is `comma` (note "a" at the end)  instead of `comm` that is causing issue. I have updated the answer as well. `comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", Session["uid"]); comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", lblAtC.Text);   comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", 1);    comma.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtShopped", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    int result = comma.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I tried but it's giving the same error with the same line

Comment: Check the update answer. Now added a new `productExists` variable and the datareader is disposed off immediately after setting the value `productExists = reader.HasRows;`

Comment: Thank you so so much, I really appreciate our help! The error is finally resolved.